# Mandatory field in Custom post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field

I am learning WordPress Plugin Development. How can I make Mandatory Fields in Custom Post ?

[image]

Comment: What method or plugin are you using for creating custom fields for this custom post type?

Comment: Thanks @JeffCohan. I am using this code `public function register_custom_post_type() {    $supports = ['title']; $labels = [ 'name'           => __( 'News', 'wpwi' ), 'singular_name'  => __( 'News', 'wpwi' ),
        'name_admin_bar' => __( 'News', 'wpwi' )
    ];$args = [ 'public' => false, 'show_ui' => true,'supports'=> $supports, 'labels'  => $labels, 'public'              => true,'description'         => 'News', 'has_archive'         => true,'exclude_from_search' => false,  ]; register_post_type( 'news', $args );
}`